# Crash when doing scrollToLocation on SectionList

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jsx, react-native-sectionlist

We have an edge case in our app. After the UI is rendered and the user tries to scroll to a section it throws `scrolltoindex should be used in conjunction with getitemlayout or on scrolltoindex failed`. Now this happens only when he does this immediately after UI render.

```
_scrollToSection = index => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.list.scrollToLocation({
            animated: true,
            itemIndex: -1,
            sectionIndex: index,
            viewPosition: 0
        });
    }, 150);
};
```

Section list render:

```
        <SectionList
            sections={this.props.sections}
            extraData={this.props.subscriber}
            ref={ref => {
                if (ref) {
                    this.list = ref;
                }
            }}
            automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={true}
            contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior={'automatic'}
            windowSize={100}
            ListHeaderComponent={this.props.header || null}
            ItemSeparatorComponent={() => (
                <Separator
                    style={[mediumStyle.separatorEnd, { backgroundColor: IOS_GREY_02_03 }]}
                />
            )}
            renderSectionFooter={() => <View style={{ height: 17 }} />}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
            removeClippedSubviews={false}
            stickySectionHeadersEnabled={true}
            renderSectionHeader={({ section }) => (
                <SectionTitle title={section.title} theme={this.props.theme} />
            )}
            renderItem={this._renderItem}
            onEndReachedThreshold={0}
            onEndReached={() => HapticFeedback.trigger()}
            scrollEventThrottle={16}
        />
```

I tried to google the cause but was unsuccessful finding only outdated and  closed issues without a solution. Did this happen to anybody else? How did you fixed it?

**UPDATE:**
We have come up on a solution of constant item sizes which also takes in count the accessibility scale factor. So we had an item and header size we could use in `getItemLayout`. All worked as should, but the `SectionList` is glitchy. When we scrolled to lower sections, the list was jumpy by itself without any interaction. 
So far the best solution we had was to build the section list ourselves in native code and use that instead of the RN list.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're getting this error because scrollToIndex has failed and you have not implemented `getItemLayout` or `onScrollToIndexFailed`

---

`getItemLayout` in a section list is not exactly fun to setup however this medium post goes over how to do it https://medium.com/@jsoendermann/sectionlist-and-getitemlayout-2293b0b916fb

They suggest `react-native-section-list-get-item-layout` to calculate the sizes of the layout https://github.com/jsoendermann/rn-section-list-get-item-layout

---

`onScrollToIndexFailed` is easier to setup you can add the prop `onScrollToIndexFailed={(info) => { /* handle error here /*/ }}` You can catch the error and then decide on how you will handle it here.

---

I would also add a check to make sure that your reference to `this.list` exists before calling the `scrollToLocation` function. Something like this.

```
_scrollToSection = index => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (this.list) {
        this.list.scrollToLocation({
            animated: true,
            itemIndex: -1,
            sectionIndex: index,
            viewPosition: 0
        });
      }
    }, 150);
};
```

Comment: I am testing this with the library you have commented for a while now but I get the same error. The other problem with it is that our items height may be different which depends on how long the title is. The other Separator, Section headers and list header are constant height. I will try the `onScrollToIndexFailed`.

Comment: Calling `scrollToLocation` (with proper getItemLayout) didn't work from `componentDidMount` but adding a delay did the trick! Thank you